# Launching lib/main.dart on LG D858HK in debug mode... Observatory connection never became ready

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter

Just set up flutter with intellij IDEA, and i get the following message on my IDEA console, when i try to run the app:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on LG D858HK in debug mode...
Observatory connection never became ready.
```

I had previously setup flutter successfully on my laptop, now tried it on my ubuntu desktop and for some reason it doesnt seem to work.
`flutter doctor` command on my terminal gives the following, if it helps:

```
 [✓] Flutter (on Linux, locale en_IN, channel alpha)
    • Flutter at /home/lordvcs/flutter
    • Framework revision d36e2f6191 (4 weeks ago), 2017-06-21 15:09:10 -0700
    • Engine revision b0dee695ec
    • Tools Dart version 1.24.0-dev.6.7

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 26.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /home/lordvcs/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-26, build-tools 26.0.0
    • Java binary at: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)

[✓] Android Studio (version 2.3)
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    • Gradle version 3.2
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.2)
    • Flutter plugin version 15.1
    • Dart plugin version 172.3317.48

[✓] Connected devices
    • LG D858HK • LGD858HK5272817 • android-arm • Android 7.1.2 (API 25)
```

Edit:
I found similar issues here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/1021

Answer (score 2):

From the terminal, I changed to the flutter project directory and ran the command `flutter run` and the application successfully ran on my device. After doing so, I restarted intellij IDEA and now when i run the the program, its working(weird).